# Revert commits back after the head was changed and pushed

Tags: git, github, git-push, git-commit, git-reset

I've committed some bad code a few days ago and today I changed and pushed an older head to master.

**Before changing head:**

commit 4

commit 3 **- bad code starts here**

commit 2 **- i set the head here and pushed**

commit 1

**After changing head:**

commit 2 **- current head**

commit 1

The problem is that now I want those 'bad commits' back.

**It is possible to get them back?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `git reflog` to solve your problem:

```
git reflog
a8U3Ild... HEAD@{10}: commit 3
e3Noj1q... HEAD@{11}: commit 4
```

Find the `SHA-1` hashes of the commits which you deleted.  The commit you want is the one for "commit 4" which was the head of the branch before you rolled things back.  Then you can reset your current branch to "commit 4" like this:

```
git checkout master
git reset --hard e3Noj1q
```

Answer (score 1):

If your deleted commits are still referenced in the reflog you should be able to restore them as explained here :
http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Maintenance-and-Data-Recovery#Data-Recovery

Man page of git reflog : http://git-scm.com/docs/git-reflog
Man page of git fsck : http://git-scm.com/docs/git-fsck